# Cannot import "util" package for ballerina

Tags: ballerina

I am using ballerina version 0.980.0 
When I import util package to my ballerina code, It shows an error said: "cannot resolve package 'ballerina/util".

Can anyone provide a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

There does not seem to be a package called `ballerina/util`. Refer to Ballerina [API docs](https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/http.html) for a list of packages provided under ballerina org-name. Maybe provide some more information on what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The util package has been removed as per the discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ballerina-dev/08P9B5-icr4). Its functions have been moved to other packages.